# Grid's attached properties always available?

Tags: wpf, xaml, attached-properties

In the xaml for this window I deleted the Grid container and put a DockPanel.
Yet, I can access a Grid's attached properties from the DockPanel. How is this possible?

Thanks!

```
<Window x:Class="testWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="testWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <DockPanel Grid.Column="2">

    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the properties are not on the instance, but are attached - meaning they are defined statically on the `Grid` class, and that the values are stored in a property container outside of the normal property system.

If you have a `DockPanel` within a `Grid`, you use `Grid.Column` to set which column the `DockPanel` should be on. Hence, they can be very useful. Attached dependency properties can also be inherited from the parent tree.

For more information, read this link:

http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/07/internals-of-dependency-property-in-wpf.html

If we take the `Grid.Column` example, the internals are that somewhere in the `Grid` class lies a definition like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Column",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(Grid),
        new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

The above code is in fact all that is needed to declare an attached dependency property. Note that there is no getter nor setter here and that the property is static. All it is, is a declaration of behavior - there is no logic to store or retrieve it.

This is because WPF has its own internal store for Dependency Properties (DPs). A normal DP has no backing fields on the classes either. In other words, all DPs are stored internally by WPF. However, WPF still keeps track of which values belong to which instances, so it is still possible to store a `Width = 20` for `TextBox1`. It also means that it is possible to store values that aren't even defined on the classes themselves - as is the case with attached DPs.

Since there are no rules for which controls `Grid.Column` can be set on, it can be stored even on controls that are not children of a Grid control.

Comment: Thanks for the followup. I do understand that the children controls are able to access attached properties of their containers. But in this case, note that the dockpanel is directly on the window and not on a grid. Yet I am able to access the Grid.Column attached property.

Comment: @soumyasg: I've tried to elaborate in my answer.. Please let me know if it isn't clear enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaborate answer. I will need to revisit Dependency/Attached properties to fully understand this. It still seems a bit blurry to me.

Comment: I guess I have one more question: in what context would someone need to set Grid.Column like the usage above when there is no grid at all in the picture?

Comment: @soumyasg: Never.. The Grid is the only class that reads the Grid.Column attached property. Anyone can use it, but Grid is the only one that does. In other words, while it is possible for anyone to use it anywhere, it only makes sense when the parent element in a Grid.

Comment: :Got it. Thanks a lot!